# Disabling IPv6 in Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: server, 18.04

I was putting the following in /etc/sysctl.conf in Ubuntu 16.04 and ipv6 was disabled.

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

In Ubuntu 18.04 I have to add the following to grub.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"
```

Just wanted to have confirmation whether this is the new way in Ubuntu 18.04 to disable IPv6.

Comment: why do you want to disable IPv6? That's considered bad practice.

Comment: Why is i a bad practice? Any links supporting this?

Comment: If you don't use IPv6, disabling it is good practice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You only need to add this to `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```

I also did it on `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to be safe.  Modifying `sysctl` only partially worked, and noticed the bug show-up in netplan, I even tried dhcp6=false to no avail.  Netplan seems to have too many bugs for 18.04 STABLE IMO but that's another story...half tempted to remove netplan also.

Just don't forget to update grub before rebooting!

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Can you clarify how this answers the question?  I am confused by your answer.

Comment: Please consider reporting the netplan bugs you found on launchpad.net! It will help the developers making it better.

Comment: Sebastian Stark - I will try to get to it, it just does not seem to pay attention to kernel settings hence why the grub command was needed, everything else used sysctl.conf except netplan.

Answer (score 16):

To clarify Stephan Rauch (for 18.04 only) -
If using grub method to disable ipv6, the /etc/sysctl.conf configuration changes were not needed.  I ended up leaving them in, (in case netplan is fixed in future) but all that is needed is the following:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Modify the GRUB_CMDLINEs to look like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```

Then execute:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Enjoy ipv4.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Do we think this would be worthy of a netplan bug or is configuring things like this through `sysctl.conf` deprecated anyway?  I couldn't find a relevant bug in https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan but perhaps I missed it?

Answer (score 5):

I think a different aproach in Ubuntu 18.04 is this one: https://pscl4rke.wordpress.com/2019/10/01/disabling-ipv6-on-ubuntu-18-04-the-netplan-version/

Just add `link-local: []` within the interface you want to disable the ipv6 link local address option. Save and test the new config with: `sudo netplan try` and if everything was okay enforce it with: `sudo netplan apply`.

Take into account that you can loss your network connection to the box if you don't know well what you are doing.

Comment: This doesn't actually disable IPv6 on the host. It just disables it in Netplan, but the IPv6 modules are still loaded, other code still see's IPv6, etc.

Comment: I needed to disable ipv6 on one interface for a storage-only LAN that only uses ipv4, while still allowing ipv6 on other interfaces.  By far the easiest method, totally convenient and effective. I think I'm actually starting to like netplan!

Comment: Disabling IPv6 totally as mentioned in /etc/default/grub can give problem with some apps requesting ipv6 compatibility out-of-the-box (i.e dovecot).

Comment: This disable the ipv6 on interface, nice answer. To disable all ipv6, you need disable it on /etc/default/grub.

Answer (score 0):

Let `sed` do the work :D

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 maybe-ubiquity"/' /etc/default/grub
sudo sed -i -e 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"/' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```