# Need to configure XRDP service to listen using IPV4 not TCP6

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp, ipv4

- I have installed xrdp on ubuntu 18.
- xrdp by default listens to 3389 so that it can support Window RDP
- When I run "netstat", it shows that
  the service is listing with tcp6 and IPV6 syntax (colon delimiters)
- Windows remote desktop client resolves the host name to an IPV4 address
- How can I configure xrdp service to listen using IPV4 protocol?
- I cannot completely disable TCP/IP v6 because I do not have the
  authority and IPV6 is needed for other services. If I know the correct configuration changes for the xrdp service I can request those changes.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046057/disabling-ipv6-in-ubuntu-18-04-server

Comment: Are you sure xrdp isn't accepting IPv4 connections? Many server programs accept incoming IPv4 connections on their IPv6 socket.

Comment: …in fact many applications that listen for incoming TCP connections don't care about the TCP/IP version of the underlying socket at all. This may just be an artefact of how `netstat` etc. list the socket.

Comment: @waltinator: OP has since clarified that this out of the question.

Comment: Thanks to all you wonderful people. Based on these comments I was able to RDP to another Ubuntu server and verify that--in fact--it does NOT matter that netstat shows tcp6. I will now look at the network security to see what problems there are.