# Can't connect to ethernet in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: network-manager, ethernet, 18.10

I know this question is quite general, but I don't know what are the problem data needed to post this question I am putting a post that is quite general in style.

What my problem is my system says that I am connected to ty internet but I can't access it. Frequently I loose connection to the internet.

My Kernel is 4.18.0.13 and I changed that version into 4.4.0.43 and it was working for some time.

But then again this problem persists.

I need a solution for this problem since my work is in peril right now for to this issue.

If you need any kind of command outputs I will post it here on further query.

Than you very much

Edit

I get the error

```
dhcp6 (eth1) request timed out
State change unknown
```

I am getting this message when i tried to restart my network 
using the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

the error is:

```
Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.serviceJob for networking.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

here are some required commands and their outputs please help me;

> ip address

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0a:eb:68:18:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:69:95:91:55:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.252/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 85929sec preferred_lft 85929sec
    inet6 fe80::e269:95ff:fe91:55f5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:82:1b:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:82:1b:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ec:28:29:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

> ip route

```
default via 192.168.0.229 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno1 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.252 metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

> cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

> cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search DLink
```

> cat /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

> nslookup ubuntu.com

```
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find ubuntu.com: SERVFAIL
```

> dig ubuntuforums.org

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-3ubuntu5-Ubuntu <<>> ubuntuforums.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 46952
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ubuntuforums.org.      IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Mon Dec 31 11:16:16 IST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 45
```

> ping 192.168.1.1

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.984 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.36 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 2ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.984/1.171/1.358/0.187 ms
```

> systemctl status networking.service

```
networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-12-31 12:29:59 IST; 21h ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
 Main PID: 1332 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: If you think you have received this message due 
Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: than a configuration issue please read the secti
Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in
Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain th
Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: process and the information we find helpful for 
Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: 
Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: exiting.
Dec 31 12:29:59 jith systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited
Dec 31 12:29:59 jith systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 31 12:29:59 jith systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
lines 1-16/16 (END)...skipping...
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-12-31 12:29:59 IST; 21h ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
 Main PID: 1332 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: 
Dec 31 12:29:56 jith dhclient[1847]: exiting.
Dec 31 12:29:59 jith systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 31 12:29:59 jith systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 31 12:29:59 jith systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

> journalctl -xe

```
 Jan 01 14:00:37 jith /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5251]: (**) Option "fd" "28"
Jan 01 14:00:37 jith /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5251]: (II) event11 - lircd-uinput: device removed
Jan 01 14:00:37 jith /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5251]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Jan 01 14:00:37 jith /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5251]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:75
Jan 01 14:00:39 jith systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 01 14:00:39 jith systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jan 01 14:00:39 jith systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
-- Subject: Unit redis-server.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit redis-server.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jan 01 14:00:40 jith systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Jan 01 14:00:40 jith systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 147.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit redis-server.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jan 01 14:00:40 jith systemd[1]: Stopped Advanced key-value store.
-- Subject: Unit redis-server.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit redis-server.service has finished shutting down.
Jan 01 14:00:40 jith systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value store...
-- Subject: Unit redis-server.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit redis-server.service has begun starting up.
Jan 01 14:00:40 jith systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Jan 01 14:00:42 jith sudo[8975]:      web : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/web ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service lircd.socket stop
Jan 01 14:00:42 jith sudo[8975]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by web(uid=0)
Jan 01 14:00:42 jith sudo[8975]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

> journalctl -xe

```
    Jan 01 16:55:34 jith avahi-daemon[1609]: New relevant interface eno1.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith NetworkManager[1618]: <info>  [1546341934.8167] device (eno1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith avahi-daemon[1609]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.252 on eno1.IPv4.
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith NetworkManager[1618]: <info>  [1546341934.8210] device (eno1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith NetworkManager[1618]: <info>  [1546341934.8213] device (eno1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed'
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith NetworkManager[1618]: <info>  [1546341934.8216] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
-- Subject: Unit resolvconf-pull-resolved.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit resolvconf-pull-resolved.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith systemd-resolved[2075]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.0.229.
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith dhclient[28822]: bound to 192.168.0.252 -- renewal in 37914 seconds.
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith NetworkManager[1618]: <info>  [1546341934.9139] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (eno1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith NetworkManager[1618]: <info>  [1546341934.9162] device (eno1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith gsd-sharing[5759]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith gsd-sharing[5759]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith nm-dispatcher[28780]: req:2 'up' [eno1]: new request (1 scripts)
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith nm-dispatcher[28780]: req:2 'up' [eno1]: start running ordered scripts...
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
-- Subject: Unit resolvconf-pull-resolved.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit resolvconf-pull-resolved.service has begun starting up.
Jan 01 16:55:34 jith systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
-- Subject: Unit resolvconf-pull-resolved.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit resolvconf-pull-resolved.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
```

Comment: `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will give you interesting messages for you to read yourself.

Comment: Do I need to post it here for your info?

Comment: Read the messages yourself. Find a few lines that describe the error you're having, then, Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1105296/edit ) your post and add those few lines, properly formatted for easy readability. DO NOT 1. Post the whole log. 2. Reply with "add Comment" with your data.

Comment: But there is a lot going in here actually, like it's from October 12 onwards and my problem started like yesterday. Is there any way I can filter older days.

Comment: I don't see an error actually.

Comment: Read `man journalctl`, and add a switch like `--since="18-12-29 01:54:37"` (example to show format for `--since` time entry)

Comment: I don't see any error specific messages in it

Comment: i had made an edit please have a look

Comment: Your default route (`default via 192.168.0.229 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 100`) sends packets via `/dev/eno1`, and `/etc/network/interfaces` configures `eth0`. Also show us results of `systemctl status networking.service` and `journalctl -xe` (at the time of the drop. Please use the formatting tools.

Comment: Are you intentionally using IPv6? `dhcp6` is an IPv6 utility. Perhaps https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046057/disabling-ipv6-in-ubuntu-18-04-server will help?

Comment: i have edited my questions according to your need, thank you very much

Comment: Not quite. run the `journalctl -xe` the instant your connection drops, not hours later.

Comment: ok, i will do that once the connection drops, can you make anything from the other command?

Comment: disabling the ipv6 for now, gets me into networking for now. But i will post here if i lost the connections  again.

Comment: hai @waltinator, the connection still getting lost, and the `journalctl -xe` is returning the same error i posted in my edited post. Please help.` 13:45:56 jith lircd-0.10.0[2939]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*`

Comment: hello @waltinator i have updated my question according to `jornalctl -xe`

Comment: I have edited my question once again,related to DNS

Answer (score 1):

I find a fresh install of ubuntu 18.10 is lacking the package libnss-resolve.
Without it, some dns name lookups (like ping pop3.comcast.net) just fail.

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-resolve
```

This installation should alter the /etc/nsswitch.conf file to have a hosts line like:

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
```

That one additional package fixed all my dns issues for 18.10, even using the default DNS nameservers supplied by dhcp and my wireless gateway.  The same fix applies to 18.04.

Comment: i don't know whether my issue is about dns?

Answer (score 0):

This will list the dns servers, 
nmcli device show | grep IP4.dns

It appears your dns servers are not configured.

Comment: i entered the command `nmcli device show | grep IP4.dns` but nothing is shown as output.

Comment: i had made an edit please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue temporarily.
I don't know if its a solution at all.

WHat i did was added two address under ipv4 settings in ubuntu network settings `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`. and i also disabled ipv6 settings as well.

But still sometimes internet cuts off and i need to turn off the internet and connect again to have a connection.

If there is anyone who knows the situation and how to resolve it please add further answers.