# IPv6 is disabled, but netfilter-persistent complains with `ip6tables-save v1.6.1: Cannot initialize: Address family not supported by protocol`

Tags: iptables, ipv6, puppet

I've disabled IPv6 on a set of Docker nodes following the instructions from [Disabling IPv6 in Ubuntu Server 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046057/disabling-ipv6-in-ubuntu-server-18-04). However, `netfilter-persistent` is still complaining about IPv6:

```
root@docker10:~# netfilter-persistent save
run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables save
run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables save
ip6tables-save v1.6.1: Cannot initialize: Address family not supported by protocol

run-parts: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables exited with return code 1
root@docker10:~#
```

How can I stop this from happening? It's leading to [Puppet errors in the logs](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-10835), and other noise.

The following commands confirm that IPv6 is disabled:

```
root@docker10:~# grep ipv6 /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
root@docker10:~# ls /proc/net/if_inet6
ls: cannot access '/proc/net/if_inet6': No such file or directory
root@docker10:~# ip address | grep inet6
root@docker10:~# sysctl -a |grep ipv6
root@docker10:~#
```